# Can't assign id to ordered list

Tags: javascript, html

I pull video titles with YouTube API and display them in an ordered list. This works great.

The goal is to click an item on the list using a voice command. The annyang library makes this easy. The problem is, I can't assign an id to my ordered list that I would use to select the ol. Adding an id to the ol breaks it.

```
function showResults(results) {
    var html = '';
    html = "<ol id="videoChoice">";
        $.each(results, function(index,value) {
        html += '<li><a data-video-    type="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + value.id.videoId + '?autoplay=1">    <img src="'  +value.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url +  '">' +     value.snippet.title + '</a>)</li>';        });
html += "</ol>";
        $('#results').html(html);
        $('#results li a').click(function(e){
        playVid($(this).attr('data-video-type'));
    });
}
```

This is how I'm accessing the list.

```
"play number *val" : function(val) {
        var test = document.getElementById('videoChoice');
    }
```

If instead of videoChoice, I reference the id 'results', it returns the results div which contains the ol and the li items, so I know this program isn't completely broken.

Why does it break if I assign an id to my ordered list?

Comment: Watch your quotes. `"<ol id="videoChoice">"` is a syntax error.

Comment: How is it a syntax error? html = "JSON data to HTML"; is the syntax, and inside of that what I'm sending is <ol id="videoChoice">

Comment: Because it's a syntax error. `html = "<ol id=\"videoChoice\">";` or `html = '<ol id="videoChoice">';` or `html = "<ol id='videoChoice'>";`. Take your pick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only posting as an answer as I can't comment but I think you're supposed to have `"<ol id='videoChoice'>"` if you're trying to give it the id 'videoChoice', or if it's a variable you want `"<ol id="+videoChoice+">"`, so if the error that breaks it is what I think it is, it's because you're closing the string before videoChoice and then starting a new one after it, if you want to give a string within a string you have to use single quotes for the inner string.

However, it can be done vice versa (i.e. with single quotes for the outer string and double quotes for the inner) which is why it works for your fifth line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks.